Where can I find more about inked cuneiform?
A recent question asked about cuneiform painted or drawn on a surface instead of being inscribed or engraved, and it seems there are three tablets from the Library of Ashurbanipal that had colophons inked on after the tablet was fired. (From that link: "In three cases the colophon was made with ink rather than impressed. Given the poor survival of ink, and the competence with which these colophons are written, it seems likely that further tablets once bore inked colophons.")
This "inked cuneiform" has a very interesting aesthetic to it, and I'd like to read more about it—it seems like a very readable way to show a sign on paper, compared to a traditional autograph. However, I haven't been able to find any other literature on it. Searching Jstor for "cuneiform" "ink", or the British Museum accession numbers of the two tablets I've found records for, hasn't yielded any results.
Where can I read more about this phenomenon?

Tablets_as_artefacts_scribes_as_artisans.pdf has info in it re ink and inking. It's a two-step thing via google to get it, I think. Not sure how I did it.

@Lambie Do you mean this one? https://www.academia.edu/2216869/Tablets_as_artefacts_scribes_as_artisans

Yes, that one is it.

Here's a great example I accidentally stumbled upon, a glazed wall-tile of fired clay showing a charioteer. There is a border of chevrons top and bottom and a cuneiform inscription, reign of Assyrian King Tukulti-Ninurta II (890 BC – 884 BC). The cuneiform is painted with the glaze.

The third inked colophon referenced in the question comes from tablet K.6677, providing a few more signs.

The Colophons of Ashurbanipal, King of the World by Taylor et al (from the book Literary Snippets, 2023) shows photos of the three inked colophons, and notes (pp 28-29):

In three examples, the colophon is even written in ink, which is very rare in cuneiform generally (see Fig. 3). This is another indication that the tablet was already dry before the colophon was added. The use of ink  was  common  at  the  time,  but  was  typically  used  for  writing  the  Aramaic  language, using Aramaic script, and usually resting on organic materials. Cuneiform is not  well  suited  to  writing  with  ink,  because  of  its  three-dimensional  nature;  few  inked inscriptions are to be expected. That notwithstanding, ink survives poorly in Iraq’s soil, so we must consider the possibility that further examples are simply no longer visible.

This is the most thorough description I've found, and no sources are cited (Taylor et al are analyzing the tablets firsthand), so I'm unsure if any more thorough analysis has ever been done.
Forrer 1926 claims that one Hittite tablet, Bo 2400, has the scribe's name inked in the colophon (p 1): "Beachtenswert ist der mit Schreibrohr und Tinte aufgemalte Name des Schreibers, das erste Beispiel dafur, wie man im Hatti-Reiche Keilschrift mit Tinte schrieb." ("Especially notable is the scribe's name, painted with a kalamos and ink: the first example of how cuneiform was written with ink in the Hittite Empire.") However, this does not seem to be the case.

Cammarosano 2024 (p 197) points out that there's another tablet, Bo 2617, which had some sort of ink on it—scribbles rather than writing—which was clearly visible in photographs a hundred years ago, but is no longer visible on the tablet now. This provides more evidence that ink doesn't survive well on clay.

The article Writing cuneiform on other media has a paragraph on "Writing cuneiform in ink".  You might be interested in reading that, and following some of the links from that page.
